# How can i read excel file and plot daily rainfall time series

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

How can I convert 08:45 time to 0845 so that I can plot time series rain fall

```
import numpy as np
import csv as csv
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import time
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
filename ='/home/yogesh/RTDAS 20 St.Data/Ambeghar_Rainfall.xls'
viewdata = pd.read_excel(filename, delimiter = ',',skiprows = 6,usecols=([3,4,5,6]))
index_col = 'Date'
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(25, 15))
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
plt.plot(viewdata["Today's Rain\n(mm)"])
plt.title("Rain Rate")
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, please show your efforts, sample data, code, any errors and desired output

Comment: import numpy as np
import csv as csv
import pandas as pd
import datetime 
import time
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

filename ='/home/yogesh/RTDAS 20 St.Data/Ambeghar_Rainfall.xls'
viewdata = pd.read_excel(filename, delimiter = ',',skiprows = 6,usecols=([3,4,5,6])) #,index_col = 'Date'

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(25, 15))
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)  
plt.plot(viewdata["Today's Rain\n(mm)"])
plt.title("Rain Rate")
plt.show()

Comment: Can you add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Edit code into your question, comments lose formatting

Comment: If that edit goes through, it still needs to be indented properly

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
filename ='/home/yogesh/RTDAS 20 St.Data/Ambeghar_Rainfall.xls'

# The standard variable name for a DataFrame is df.
df = pd.read_excel(filename, delimiter = ',', skiprows=6,usecols=([3,4,5,6]))

#I'm not sure if this is used later, or if you're trying to set index_col as your column name.
index_col = 'Date'
df = df.set_index(index_col)

# If you're only looking to plot a single column this is often easier:
df["Today's Rain\n(mm)"].plot(figsize=(25, 15))
plt.title("Rain Rate")
plt.show()
```